# opencv - how to check contour location

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

Im trying to draw cars on lane using opencv, and when a car get out of the lane i want to draw it contour in red .[lane are white and cars are green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6WNb.png)

I have tried with finding if the cnt is curently on black pixel, but i dont know how to do it...

```
def frameDiffer(path):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    ret,oldFrame = cap.read()
    oldGrayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(oldFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    
    while ret:
        Roi = cv2.imread('blackAndWhiteRoad.jpg')
        ret, newFrame = cap.read()
        if ret == False: break
        newGrayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(newFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        result = cv2.absdiff(newGrayFrame,oldGrayFrame)
        if np.max(result)>10 :
            result = cv2.threshold(result, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            result = cv2.GaussianBlur(result,(7,7),4)
    
            contours,_ = cv2.findContours(result,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            for cnt in contours:
                if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>150:
                    cv2.drawContours(Roi,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)  

            cv2.imshow('result',cv2.resize(Roi,(960,600)))  
            cv2.imshow('newFrame',cv2.resize(newFrame,(960,600)))   
    
        oldGrayFrame = newGrayFrame
    
        if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'): break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello :) get the bounding box somthing like this x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) and then Compare it to the other position you want.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple way to interpret "out of lane".
I will define "out of lane" to be center point is not on the lane.

```py
from tomni.contour_operations import get_center
center = get_center(cnt)
# Note that X and Y are swapped between CV2/Tomni and Numpy
if Roi[center[1], center[0]] > 128: # center point is a white pixels
   cv2.drawContours(Roi,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)
else:
   cv2.drawContours(Roi,cnt,-1,(255,0,0),2)
```

An other option is by overlap.

```py
single_car = np.zeros_like(Roi)
cv2.drawContours(single_car ,cnt,-1,1,-1) # -1 means it fills it completely
overlap = single_car * (Roi > 128)

if np.sum(overlap) > threshold:
```

Overlap is now 1 if the contour AND lane are in that pixels otherwise it is zero.
Sum gives you the absolute overlap.

You can defied it by the np.sum(single_car) to find out what part of the car overlaps the lane.